# when I implement splash screen, application get crashed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have tried 2 different ways to implement splashscreen.
1) By changing code in launch_background.xml that works well but it just destroy images. like it show small image to very large size. and when I apply my real splash screen image application get crashed but application is working well with other images but image size problem in every image. so I need to know how to set the size of the image into this file and how to avoid to crash the application
2) I use  splash screen  package that also have a problem in this image size is very very small in the center of the screen I want to have it as full background.

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        />
</item>
```

This is the code for 3rd problem

```
class splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _splashState createState() =>  _splashState();
}

class _splashState extends State<splash> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SplashScreen(
        seconds: 4,
        navigateAfterSeconds:  MyApp(),
        image:  Image.asset('imges/bg.png'),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue just prefer to make custom splash screen and put any type of functionality as you want.
Here is the sample I did try that will work fine for you. Make sure to use `Navigator.pushReplacement` in such a way when you need to get back from home screen it would not stay on spalsh it will exit as it should be logically. import packages according to your need.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: splash(),
  ));
}

class splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _splashState createState() =>  _splashState();
}

class _splashState extends State<splash> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
          () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => yournextpagename(),
      ),
    ));
  }

  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox.expand(
              child: Image.asset('imges/splash.png',fit: BoxFit.fill,),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah I did find another solution but I am facing a problem there to. let me try this.

Comment: which type of issue? can you share the code I will modify it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Developer,
Just try this way, no need to use any external packages...**

````
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreenAnimate> {
  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 8);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

    if (_seen)
      return false;
    else {
      prefs.setBool('seen', true);
      return true;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Center(
        child: new Image.asset('assets/images/splash_screen.png',
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
    );
  }

  navigationPage() async {
    bool isFirstSeen = await checkFirstSeen();

    if (isFirstSeen) {
      return Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/onboardscreen');
    }

    if (kAdvanceConfig['IsRequiredLogin']) {
      return Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
    }

    return Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
  }
}```
````